# A table has two columns - how we can get the full_name into one column?

Tags: sql-server

I am following sample data in SQL Table:-

```
First_Name   Last_Name   Concatenation(F_Name,L_Name)
-------------------------------------------------------------
Mohd         Nazir       Mohd,Nazir
```

I want to see the result as

```
Full_Name = Mohd Nazir
```

within the same table

Comment: `SELECT First_Name + ' ' + LAst_Name As Full_Name ...` ;).

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTableNameHere
ADD FullName AS ISNULL(First_Name, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(Last_Name, '')
```

With this *computed* column, you have a new column in your table that'll always contain the concatenation of first and last name, separated by a space